# Stretching vertical space and reducing badness at the bottom of a page

Tags: page-breaking, documentclass-writing, sections-paragraphs, badness, penalty

#### Problem

Is there a way in TeX/LaTeX to somehow reduce the badness which comes from a distance of a line from target height of a page?

#### Context

I am creating a document class for my students to use LaTeX, rather than MS Word, to automate portable document creation. The students are expected to have no familiarity with LaTeX whatsoever, so I would like to automatically handle as many of corner cases as possible in my LaTeX class.

At the same time, my institution has requirements to the types of documents, which I am trying to cover, when it comes to fonts, spaces, justifications etc. However, it is allowed for bottom page margins to be somewhat inconsistent across a document.

In particular, it is required that theses should use specific fonts of 14pt in size with 1.5 interline interval. Therefore, `xelatex` is used for compilation, and, more importantly, the badness conditioned upon a vertical distance of a line from bottom of a page grows much faster than in ordinary TeX/LaTeX documents.

The following MWE reproduces the problem (with `pdflatex` too):

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\ifhmode\par\fi\addvspace{0.5em}\textbf{#1}\par
   \penalty201\addvspace{0.5em}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\ifhmode\par\fi\addvspace{0.5em}\textbf{\textit{#1}}\par\penalty301}

\begin{document}

\parskip=1em\raggedbottom
\tracingonline=1\tracingpages=1

1\par2\par3\par4\par5\par6\par7\par8\par9\par10\par11\par12\par13\par14\par
15\par16\par17\par18\par19\par20\par21\par22

\section{Section 1}\section{Section 2}\subsection{Subsection}
\par23

\end{document}
```

which produces the result (here for readability I artificially cropped the image and reduced the page margins):
[image: cropped result of compilation]

Page tracing yields (the part between the pages):

```
% t=472.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=499.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=201 c=100000#
% t=526.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=201 c=100000#
% t=553.0 g=550.0 b=* p=301 c=*
[1]
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
% t=10.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=301 c=100000#
% t=32.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
```

In this example I would like the section 2 to be on the same page as the subsection, and I want the subsection to be on the same page as the paragraph "23" respecting the surrounding penalties.

I know I could just assign infinitely bad `\penalty 10000` after a section title, but that would introduce another problem. It seems common to me that people first define a structure of content placing empty chapters/sections/subsections etc., and then they fill-in the content proper. With infinite penalty all such sections would be on the same page and placed beyond the page border. And this is what `\@startsection` does.

That is, I would like a possibility of a page break between Section 1 and Section 2 in the MWE albeit with a penalty.

The only way to achieve these goals that I was able to find is by playing around with `\parskip` stretch (5em in the real example) and shrinkage, though it does not seem to be a reliable solution, it would introduce a possibility of violating requirements of the institution, and I've heard that it is generally undesired in typography. Therefore, I would rather make the bottom margin stretchable but without making badness infinite in order to respect penalties, and my question is about a possibility of doing so in a LaTeX class.

I also tried using `\raggedbottom` and `\def\@textbottom{...}` for it, but they don't affect badness/costs of page breaks in any way. I compared resulting PDFs using the `diff-pdf` tool, placing those macros do not make any difference at all.

Comment: You could simply use `\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\goodbreak}` instead of redefining sectioning commands. That would allow a page breaks between both sectioning commands. And please do not tell your students that they don't need to know anything about LaTeX. Regardless how well you prepare the class, they will get errors and use commands wrongly and will have to learn how to handle that. Point them to some site like learnlatex.org.

Comment: I would use a standard latex `\@startsection` definition, you are losing so much by these redefinitions, control over: page breaking, indentation widows lines in the first paragraph, page headings, tables of contents,...  you can address consecutive sections  by using the hook Ulrike mentioned and conditionally add a penalty if you are immediately after a section, which (if your section was defined with `\@startsection`) you can tell as it will have set `\@afterheading` flags

Comment: Thank you both for the quick responses and tips. I actually do other things too in the definitions of sections including toc handling, pdf bookmarking, indentation, handling of non-ascii characters and formatting control sequences via expl3 in section headers etc.

Comment: As for orphans and widows, ``\@startsection`` only disallows widows by setting infinite club penalty (in ``\@afterheading``), which disregards badness. Yet orphans can still happen due to infinite badness, which can actually be reproduced in the given MWE by defining ``\section`` as ``\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{0.5em}{0.5em}{\bfseries}`` (with or without ``\goodbreak`` and with default ``\subsection``), placing the sections after the paragraph 21, and then adding a paragraph of three lines into the section 2.

Comment: That is, the problem with badness still persists, if I use ``\section`` or ``\@startsection``.

Reacting to flags set by ``\@afterheading`` and ``\@startsection`` does not make a difference (compared to a simple use of any finite penalty, e.g. ``\goodbreak``), because it basically means: check, if ``\nobreak`` is in place, i.e. we are right under a section title, and, if it is, place a finite penalty (``\goodbreak`` or any other, because, again, of infinite badness); otherwise, use the finite penalty of an ordinary paragraph, which is also finite.

Comment: Also, I am not going to tell the students they "don't need to know anything about LaTeX". What I am saying is that when a new group of 30 or so students, who have never used LaTeX, are given the task to use it (for, say, preparing a lab report) based mostly on examples and a workbook, I would prefer not to overwhelm them with too many of TeX and LaTeX commands, nor do I want them to "cut corners" using stuff like ``\pagebreak``, where it is unnecessary. That is, I am trying to minimize the probability of them encountering cases which require special handling.

Comment: Of course, if there is no way of making a LaTeX compiler respect non-infinite vertical penalties, when height of a line is bigger than usual, we will have to deal with it, and I will accept that as an answer (after a couple of months in hope for a positive response).